# Getting only name of the files from a folder without the full path in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, path

Hi I want to get only name of the files from a folder without the full path. Here is my code so far (asp.net)

```
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Files/"));      

    List<string> filenames = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
        filenames.Add(files[i]);             
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = filenames;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

How would I accomplish this in asp.net 
Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

filenames.Add(Path.GetFileName(files[i]));

Comment: Thanks Kremena Lalova. You just solved my issue. You made it so easy thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
string[] files = 
Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Files/")).Select(fi => Path.GetFileName(fi);
```

Also add reference to this

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Hi rs thanks to you but I am getting an Error 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'string[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You probably don't have a reference to `System.Linq`.

Answer (score 1):

Try [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles.aspx).

This will return an array of [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) which will give you what you want and more.